# Where can I get bitcoin customer support? Is there a support number?

Tags: services

I have a bitcoin problem. My transaction is unconfirmed, etc

Is there a support number that bitcoin users can call for help?

Comment: There is no support number for bitcoin - It's a decentralized network, with no central authority behind it. You would need to share some basic information such as the txid and wallet you are using before anyone here could try to help

Answer (score 9):

Bitcoin is not a business, it is a decentralized computer network, where no one person or organization is in charge. Thus there is no customer support number for bitcoin, like you may be used to with your bank, credit card, etc.

Note that even though bitcoin itself is not run by a business, there are businesses that operate within the bitcoin ecosystem. For customer support regarding those businesses, you'll need to contact them directly.

But for general bitcoin questions, you're in the right place to ask for support regarding your problems. Just like bitcoin is a decentralized cryptocurrency where no particular person is in charge, its 'support team' is also decentralized and scattered across the world. I put 'support team' in quotations because the participants of this Stack Exchange site are not employees of bitcoin or Stack Exchange, instead, they are here of their own accord, volunteering their time and knowledge to help others. There are many users here with a great knowledge regarding cryptocurrencies, so if you ask a good question, you will likely receive a great reply.

You could elaborate on your problem a bit for a better response.

- Where did you do the transaction?
- Did you pay the miner fees?
- Did your wallet software give any response?
- Were you trading/transacting on an exchange?
- The transaction id (`TXID`)
- Did your transaction make it to the memory pool (`mempool`)?

I see that you're new to StackExchange.

Please edit your question for some significant help.